# Table from 2D array in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, 2d

I'm stuck on something that I was expecting with AngularJS to work out of the box without any issues, and yet strangely enough...

I'm using a JSON service that returns data as a 2D array:

```
$scope.data= [
    ["val-11", "val-12", "val-13"],
    ["val-21", "val-22", "val-23"]
    ];
```

From this I'm trying to generate a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">
<td ng-repeat="col in row">{{col}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I don't understand why AngularJS doesn't handle such a basic scenario. I can get correct $index for the parent loop, if I need it, I can iterate through the values, but only with one loop like this "col in data[0]", but I cannot get any result trying to use the nested loop as shown above.

Am I doing something wrong? It just seems to be too basic not to work right away. Please somebody help me with this bizarre issue.

Comment: working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/AWkQj/

Comment: I found the problem (see below), it is just a plain bug. Too bad somebody down-voted my question, it is a serious issue for AngularJS team to resolve.

Comment: You should see an error in your console with a link to  http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat:dupes

Comment: Yes, the following syntax seems to work with 1.2 RC2:   <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
            <td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index">
                {{col}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>. But it doesn't work in earlier released versions, which means it is a breaking feature. Thank you for pointing this out. I did like the way it worked in earlier versions though, because this is what anyone would expect it to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Angular 1.0.x the ng-repeat directive had numerous bugs caused by trying to "guess" whether non-object values (i.e. strings or numbers) had been added, removed or moved.
The problem is that non-objects have no identity of their own, so it is impossible to track them accurately. This was problematic in a number of cases and also caused the ngRepeat code to be bloated with loads of workarounds and edge cases.

In 1.2 we improved the syntax for ng-repeat to allow the developer to specify for themselves exactly how to identify items in a collection.  This is done by the "track by" keyword. One consequence of this is that we disallow items which have the same identifier.

By default ng-repeat will try to track by the value of the item. If you have repeated items such as the same object or identical strings or numbers then ng-repeat will complain and you will see the error in the console.

```
var TableCtrl = function($scope) {
  $scope.data= [
    ["", "", "val-13"]
  ];
}
```

Here the first two items in the sub-array are the same "empty" string. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tEU8r/

If you really do want to have repeated items in the collection then you need to provide a method for ng-repeat to distinguish them.  The simplest and obvious approach is to track the items by their position in the collection.  This is done by using "track by $index".  Here is the same example but fixed in this way:

```
<table ng-controller="TableCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
    <td ng-repeat="col in row track by $index">
       {{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}} {{col}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h44Z8/

So this is not a bug in AngularJS.  But you are correct that people should be aware of this change when upgrading to 1.2